# Preventing repetition of same number that created randomly

Tags: c, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {

    int i,j,z,w,c; /* counter*/
    int ticket[6],n[6];
    int a; /*numbers of one ticket*/
    int x; /* Random numbers of tickets*/
    int num; /*Quantity of tickets*/
    int loser = 0; /*initialize the number of known-tickets*/
    int threeknown = 0;
    int fourknown = 0;
    int fiveknown = 0;
    int winner = 0;


    srand (time(NULL));


    printf ("Please enter the lucky ticket numbers between 0 and 50\n");

    for (i=0;i<6;i++) { /* loop for entering numbers of ticket from keyboard*/
        scanf ( "%d",&a);
        if (a<50 && a>0){
        ticket[i] = a;
        }
        else {
             printf ("\a ERROR: Please enter number between 0 and 50\n");
             i--; /* enter again */
        }
        }
    printf ("Lucky ticket is:\n");
    for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
        printf ("%3d",ticket[i]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    printf ("Please enter the quantity of tickets\n\a");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    for (z=0;z<num;z++) {  /* For each ticket */
        for (j=1;j<=6;j++) {
            x = 1 + rand()%49;
            n[j] = x;
            printf ("%3d",n[j]);
            }

            printf("\n\n");
            }
    for (z=0;z<num;z++){  /*counter for each ticket control */
        if (ticket[0]==n[0] && ticket[1]==n[1] && ticket[2]==n[2] && ticket[3]==n[3] && ticket[4]==n[4] && ticket[5]==n[5]) {
                            winner += 1;
                            }
        if (ticket[0]==n[0] && ticket[1]==n[1] && ticket[2]==n[2] && ticket[3]==n[3] && ticket[4]==n[4]) {
                            fiveknown += 1;
                            }
        if (ticket[0]==n[0] && ticket[1]==n[1] && ticket[2]==n[2] && ticket[3]==n[3]) {
                            fourknown += 1;
                            }
        if (ticket[0]==n[0] && ticket[1]==n[1] && ticket[2]==n[2]) {
                            threeknown += 1;
                            }
        else {
             loser += 1;
             }
                             }
        printf ("Number of winners : %d\n",winner);
         printf ("Number of five-knowns : %d\n",fiveknown);
          printf ("Number of four-knowns : %d\n",fourknown);
           printf ("Number of three-knowns : %d\n",threeknown);
              printf ("Number of losers : %d\n",loser);


        system ("PAUSE");
        return 0;

        }
```

I have project about C coding Bingo Program. I need to maintain a winner ticket from keyboard between 0 and 50 (12 34 23 11 47 4) and then I need to generate tickets randomly. In these tickets none of them have the same number and the sorting is not important. For example ( 23 12 10 4 9 46 ). My question is to how to have these kind of tickets ? I don't want to have this kind of tickets ( 12 43 20 12 9 4 )

Answer (score 3):

Build an array of the fifty acceptable values, choose one, and then remove it from the array.

Since the order in the array is not important, you can remove it at little cost by overwriting it with the last value and decreasing the "array count" variable.

```
void RemoveFromArray(int* arr, size_t *pNumberOfElements, size_t indexToRemove)
{
    //Note: I'm not putting the error/bounds checking because it's not what the question is about.
    size_t indexLast = *pNumberOfElements - 1;
    arr[indexToRemove] = arr[indexLast];
    (*pNumberOfElements)--;
}

void ChooseRandom6of50(int* random6ints)
{
    int arr[50];
    size_t nElements = 50;
    {
        size_t i;
        for(i=0 ; i<50 ; i++)
            arr[i] = (int)(i+1); //Fill with values 1 to 50
    }
    {
        size_t iDest;
        for(iDest=0 ; iDest<6 ; iDest++)
        {
            int rnd = rand() % nElements; //The real code should use the more elaborate random formula
            size_t randIndex = rnd;
            random6ints[iDest] = arr[randIndex];
            RemoveFromArray(arr, &nElements, randIndex);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a small number of tickets picked, the easiest way is to draw tickets randomly as you did already, but draw again if the ticket is already in the lot of drawn ticktes until you have a new ticket:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX

int contains(int ticket[], int n, int which)
{
    while (n-- > 0) {
        if (ticket[n] == which) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void draw(int ticket[], int n, int m)
{
    int i, t;

    if (n > m) return;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        do {
            t = rand() % m;
        } while (contains(ticket, i, t));
        ticket[i] = t;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int ticket[6];
    int i;

    draw(ticket, 6, 50);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) printf("%4d", ticket[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `draw` function does not do anything if the number of tickets to draw, `n`, is bigger than the tickets available, `m`, because that would lead to an infinite loop. If `n == m` the draw is like shuffling, albeit in a very inefficient way. (The `draw` function should probably return an error code or abort the program in that case, but in oder to keep things simple, I've left that out.)

The `contains` function should also come in handy if you want to compare the user's tickets with the draw. (Also, it would look more like programming if you could turn your variable `threeknown`, `fiveknown` and so on into an array `hits[7]`.)